# CORS error with socket.io-client on IE

Tags: node.js, internet-explorer, socket.io, cors

I'm having an issue with IE and CORS.

On my page "mysite.com", I do :

Client-side :

```
<script src="http:// assets.mysite.com/bundle.js"> //without the space
```

On the assets server, I have :

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
});
```

The bundle.js is a browserified module which connects to a socket server :

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')("http: //mysocketserver.com:5000/api");
```

No problem on Chrome and Firefox, everything is loaded perfectly, connection established, etc. On IE (surprisingly) things are not so well.

```
SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for http://mysocketserver:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1430944033665-4&sid=jvRj85_i_1ZgwTumAABK required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).
```

I've checked everything. IE uses the same transport as Chrome and FF, the socket request has the following headers on all browsers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials    true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin http:// mysite.com
```

Yet IE refuses to connect and, I can't figure out why.

Answer (score -1):

Because it is IE ;) Especially IE 8/9 will have such problems across domains. Try using XDomain, it worked for me and solved such problems.

Comment: It's actually IE11, and works on my gf's PC, which is on the same connection, next to mine. Go figure... Anyway, 50% success rate with IE is already a lot.